# Specify initial choice for a form `ModelChoiceField`

Tags: python, django, forms

I cannot figure out how to specify initial choice for `ModelChoiceField`. Is there any caveat that I am missing?

```
class QuizUserForm(forms.Form):
    question = forms.CharField()
    eq_answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuizUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['mcq_answer_choice'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.MCQChoice.objects.filter(
        question__prompt=kwargs['initial']['question']), initial=1, widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        empty_label=None)
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using? What wrong with that approach, is that raising an error?

Comment: I am using Django 1.9. I do not know why, but it does not set initial choice, however, from the `queryset` I am getting all necessary choices. So, `queryset` works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `initial` equal to model instance. Also it is better, to specify field on class level and update params in `__init__`

```
class QuizUserForm(forms.Form):
    question = forms.CharField()
    eq_answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    mcq_answer_choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=models.MCQChoice.objects.none(),
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        empty_label=None
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuizUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        queryset = models.MCQChoice.objects.filter(
            question__prompt=kwargs['initial']['question']
        )
        self.fields['mcq_answer_choice'].queryset = queryset
        self.fields['mcq_answer_choice'].initial = queryset.first()
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that `initial` should be an object of MCQChoice